# Python re.sub repl w/ functions, bug or correct behavior?

Tags: python

It is known that the *repl* in re.sub can accept a function. The first code snippet below calls the account function, but replaces all matches with the same account number. The second code snippet produces the expected behavior.

Is this how re.sub was meant to work? Why does the first snippet fail?

### First Snippet

```
def accountNumberGen():
    acc_id_gen= lambda: (random.randint(1000000000000,9999999999999))
    acc_val = str(acc_id_gen())
    return acc_val

def changeFiles():
    for filename in os.listdir(file_dir):
        for line in fileinput.input(file_dir + '\\' + filename, inplace=True):
            search = re.search('\d{13}', line)
            line = re.sub('\d{13}', accountNumberGen(), line)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

### Second Snippet

```
def accountNumberGen(something):
    acc_id_gen= lambda: (random.randint(1000000000000,9999999999999))
    acc_val = str(acc_id_gen())
    return acc_val

def changeFiles():
    for filename in os.listdir(file_dir):
        for line in fileinput.input(file_dir + '\\' + filename, inplace=True):
            search = re.search('\d{13}', line)
            line = re.sub('\d{13}', accountNumberGen, line)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: "It is known…" So even Dothraki are using Python now. :)

Answer (score 3):

`accountNumberGen()` does not name a function; it *calls* the function `accountNumberGen`, and the return value of this call (a string) is used as the "repl" argument to `re.sub`.  To pass a function as an argument, you must simply write the name of the function (`accountNumberGen`), which is why the second code snippet works.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches give the correct output if there is only one substitution to be done on each line. However, it makes a difference if

1. the function is provided as a parameter to `re.sub()` or
2. the value returned from the function is provided

... if there is more than one substitution to be made on each line. With the function provided, it is called once for each substitution but with the value of the function provided, the same value is used each time.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import re,random,sys

def accountNumberGen1():
    acc_id_gen= lambda: (random.randint(100,999))
    acc_val = str(acc_id_gen())
    return acc_val

def accountNumberGen(something):
    return accountNumberGen1()

acct = ['000 009 a','001 008 b','002 007 c','003 006 d']

for line in acct:
    line = re.sub('\d{3}', accountNumberGen1(), line)
    sys.stdout.write(line+"\n")

sys.stdout.write ("\n")

for line in acct:
    line = re.sub('\d{3}', accountNumberGen, line)
    sys.stdout.write(line+"\n")
```

... which produces the output:

```
943 943 a
234 234 b
802 802 c
974 974 d

429 753 a
189 459 b
225 863 c
178 114 d
```

... with different random values substituted each time when the function is passed to `re.sub()`.